# Magento 2.3.3 Incompatible argument type

Tags: magento2.3, theme, command-line

Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 50 secs 351.0 MiBErrors during compilation:

> Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Brand\Collection
>           Incompatible argument type: Required type: 
>           \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface. Actual type: 
>           \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb; File: 
>       /var/www/html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Brand/Collection.php

Total Errors Count: 1

In Log.php line 92: Error during compilation

setup:di:compile
 [] []

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Brand;

 class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection {
/**
 * store view id
 * @var int
 */
protected $_storeViewId = null;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManager;

protected $_addedTable = [];

protected function _construct() {
    $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\Brand', 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Brand');
}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
 * @param \Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract $connection
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    $connection = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
) {
    parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection);
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;

    if ($storeViewId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()) {
        $this->_storeViewId = $storeViewId;
    }
}

/**
 * get store view id
 * @return int [description]
 */
public function getStoreViewId() {
    return $this->_storeViewId;
}

/**
 * set store view id
 * @param int $storeViewId [description]
 */
public function setStoreViewId($storeViewId) {
    $this->_storeViewId = $storeViewId;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Multi store view
 * @param string|array $field
 * @param null|string|array $condition
 */
public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null) {
    $attributes = array(
        'name',
        'status',
        'click_url',
        'image_alt',
        'store_id',
    );
    $storeViewId = $this->getStoreViewId();
    if (in_array($field, $attributes) && $storeViewId) {
        if (!in_array($field, $this->_addedTable)) {
            $this->getSelect();
            $this->_addedTable[] = $field;
        }
        // return parent::addFieldToFilter("IF($field.value IS NULL, main_table.$field, $field.value)", $condition);
        return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
    }
    if ($field == 'store_id') {
        $field = 'main_table.brand_id';
    }
    return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
}

/**
 * Multi store view
 */
protected function _afterLoad() {
    parent::_afterLoad();
    if ($storeViewId = $this->getStoreViewId()) {
        foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
            $item->setStoreViewId($storeViewId)->getStoreViewValue();
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * set order random by brand id
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function setOrderByBrand()
{
    $this->getSelect()->order('order');

    return $this;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is the constructor of the parent class

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
```

In your class constructor change the line

```
$connection = null,
```

To

```
\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
```

Then add $resource in your parent construct so it look like this and match the class needed for the parent constructor

```
parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection,$resource);
```